# SQL syntax error in php for login form

Tags: php, mysql

I am just trying to run a simple line of SQL in php but for some reason it does not work and just returns that I have a syntax error.
 `$query = "SELECT * FROM 'Catalogue' WHERE 'username' = '$u_n' AND 'password' = '$psw' ;";`
and when I try to run it I get this

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''Catalogue' WHERE 'username' = 'konsskou' AND 'password' =
>   '1234'' at line 1

where konsskou is the username I entered and 1234 the respective password. What could I be missing and made me struggle so much?

Comment: @F0XS You're missing the quotes around the variables. Though using prepared statements and parameter binding really is better to prevent SQL injection and quoting issues.

Comment: `$query = "SELECT * FROM Catalogue WHERE username = '".$u_n."' AND password = '".$psw."' ;";` My bad, thanks @aynber